# Laravel 5 отношения belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel

Есть модель Resta и Kitchen. Cвязал их через `belongsToMany`. Вот так проверяю на запрос по заданным `id`

```
Resta::whereHas('kitchens', function ($query)use ($kitchen) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $kitchen);
})->get();
```

А как проверить сразу в двух пивотных таблицах? Написал аналогично там же для второй модели, но это не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я поняла из вашего комментария, вам нужно что-то такое

```
Resto::whereHas('kitchens', function ($query) use ($kitchen) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $kitchen);
})
->whereHas('services', function ($query) use ($services) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $services);
})
->get();
```

Comment: это не сработает, уже пробывал

Comment: что получается в результате?

Comment: find(kitchen) разве find найдет мне то что может придти как массив ? ну и в общем еще такая картина find не поймет мои пивотные таблицы 
` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'restos.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) from `services` inner join `resto_service` on `services`.`id` = `resto_service`.`service_id` where `resto_service`.`resto_id` = `restos`.`id` and `services`.`id` is null limit 1) `

Comment: Что у вас таблицах resto_service и resto, такое ощущение что где-то название таблицы перепутали в модели или связи

Comment: нет не может быть путаницы(если бы они были у меня не работали бы отношения, я бы не смог юзать attach() sync()).

Comment: два whereHas -а не срабатывают вот что я пытался вам сказать

Comment: исправил кое какие вещи сработало

Answer (score 0):

Сложно ответить на вопрос не видя общей реализации, но у меня 2 предложения.

1. Если вы проверяете id в пивотных таблицах, используйте `contains()` чтобы проверить наличие ключа в коллекции.

   $model->ManytoManyModel->contains($id)
2. Если у вас архитектура связи с 2мя пивотными таблицами, может целесообразнее будет использовать **morphTo()** или **morphToMany()**? Конечно, нужно видеть всю вашу архитектуру и знать цели.

Comment: я имел ввиду что модель Resta связывается еще с одной моделью там тоже отношения многие к многим кроме kitchens мне нужно проверить еще services
`$services = Request::get('services');
       
        $kitchen = Request::get('kitchen');
        
        $restos = Resto::whereHas('kitchens', function ($query)use ($kitchen) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $kitchen);
            })->get();`

Comment: @Rai, Тогда объясните поподробнее. Вам нужна коллекция выборки сразу из 2 пивоток? Или же проверка на существование связи? Цель пожалуйста озвучьте)) И что вы запрашиваете через Request::get('services') и Request::get('kitchen') ? Их id из формы на клиенте?

Comment: Да это их id, цель такова в Request те приходят id кухни и сервиса после мне нужно вытащить объекты у которых есть в пивотных таблицах эти id 
например `$kitchen= [1,2]` `$services=[3,4]`

Comment: Тогда, могу посоветовать попробовать Request::input вместо Request::get. По логике, выборка whereHas определяет отношения и при помощи колбэка с тайп хинтом Closure производит выборку по условиям. По идее, все должно работать, но если не заработает, необходимо будет увидеть архитектуру таблиц kitchens, services и restos, а так же их модели.

Comment: два whereHas -а не срабатывают вот что я пытался вам сказать